# JSF header outputLabel not creating labels for indexed components

Tags: jsf, label, wai-aria

I'm fixing broken accessibility features in our company website.  Here's a greatly simplified and anonymized version of the JSF for a particular page:

```
<h:form id="mainForm">
  <h:panelGroup>
    <h:dataTable id="myDataTable">

      <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
          <h:panelGrid columns="1">
            <h:outputLabel for="myDropdownMenu" value="Number" />
          </h:panelGrid>
        </f:facet>
        <h:panelGrid columns="1">
          <h:panelGroup>
            <h:selectOneMenu id="myDropdownMenu">
              <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.numberList}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
          </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGrid>
      </h:column>

    </h:dataTable>
  </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

When this is translated into HTML, the `label` has the following `for` property:

```
<label for="myDataTable:myDropdownMenu">Number</label>
```

which does not match the id of the dropdown, since there can be multiple rows of data and each one gets an index number added to the id:

```
<select id="myDataTable:0:myDropdownMenu">
```

The only solution I've been able to find is to add another `outputLabel` inside the inner `panelGroup`:

```
        <h:panelGrid columns="1">
          <h:panelGroup>
            <h:selectOneMenu id="myDropdownMenu">
              <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.numberList}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            
            <h:outputLabel for="myDropdownMenu" value="Number" />

          </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGrid>
```

This makes the `for` property match the actual `id`, but it also makes each row of data display the label (in addition to the label being up at the header), which I don't want.

What's the best way to put a label on the dropdown without displaying additional text?

Comment: This is not a JSF problem. Take a step back. How exactly do you want the generated HTML output to look like? Once you know exactly this, then simply reframe your question to instead ask how to write JSF code in such way that exactly the desired HTML output is generated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your grid is not rendering a correct table markup, using `<thead>` and `<th>` elements that assistive technology can use to resolve the label for each select cell, you do need a label for each individual select menu.

You can hide it visually though, by using [aria-labelledby](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-labelledby). Curiously, you already referenced to ARIA as a tag but you’re not using it.

```xml
<h:outputLabel id="myDropdownMenuLabel" value="Number" />
…
<h:selectOneMenu aria-labelledby="myDropdownMenuLabel">
```